# Yii2 (ActiveRecord) цикличная вставка в таблицу

Tags: yii2, activerecord

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить такую проблему:
есть модель (таблица) с 2ми полями id txt_value
в цикле делаю вставку, вот такой код

```
$model = new NewTestTable();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $model->isNewRecord = true;
    $model->txt_value = "_text_" . uniqid();;
    $model->save();
}
```

При таком коде, на втором проходе, получаю ошибку

> ERROR: Duplicate key value violates unique constraint "new_test_table_pkey"
> DETAIL: Key "(id)=(35)" already exists.

Как можно выполнить циклическую вставку?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isNewRecord` всего лишь определяет надо сделать `insert` (если `true`) или `update` (если `false`). Однако внутри движка нет функции, которая при этом очищала бы ненужные поля, т.к. движок не знает что именно вы бы хотели обнулить.

Поэтому по сути ваш запрос всегда выглядит так:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (id, txt_value) VALUES (value1, value2);
```

Т.к. модель всегда одна и та же, то после первой итерации модель получает идентификатор вставленной записи и `$model->id` становится не пустым. На второй итерации `isNewRecord` говорит, что **надо произвести операцию insert** при этом `id` уже будет существовать в таблице и совпадать с тем, что написано в указанной модели с предыдущей итерации.

По сути, чтобы решить проблему нужно

1. Либо делать `unset($model->id);` на итерации
2. Либо просто на каждой итерации создавать новую модель, т.е. `$model = new NewTestTable();` внести внутрь цикла

Comment: Спасибо большое !

Comment: Остановился на варианте  - делать unset($model->id); на итерации

Comment: @cln2008 если ответ помог - можно ткнуть знак "галочка" слева от ответа)

Comment: ткнул ))
еще раз спасибо !